# Changing the on screen text and the button text when pressing the coded button in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Could someone, please, advise me on how to change a code so the screen text and coded button text stays until next click of the mouse button and not dissapear after releasing a mouse button?
For now when I click and hold the mouse button the screen text is changing, but the coded button is not updating. And also after I release the mouse button, text is coming back to the initial state.
I need the text (both on the screen and on the button) to change and stay updated on the screen forever or until mouse button is clicked again.
I made a function to blit the text on the screen and a class for drawing a button on the screen. And they both work. Maybe the problem is somewhere in the main logic with 'if' statements?

````
pygame.init()

# setting the window size and FPS
SIZE = WIDTH, HEIGHT = (640, 640)
FPS = 30
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

bgcolor = (54, 54, 54)

# defining the function to draw text on the screen
def draw_text(surface, text, pos):
    text_color = (255, 255, 255)
    text_font = pygame.font.SysFont('Times New Roman', 24)
    x, y = pos

    word_surface = text_font.render(text, 1, text_color)
    surface.blit(word_surface, (x, y))


# defining a class for buttons
class DrawButton():
    def __init__(self, button_text, button_x, button_y):
        self.button_text = button_text
        self.button_x = button_x
        self.button_y = button_y
        self.button_color_passive = (89, 89, 89)
        self.button_color_active = (212, 200, 235)
        self.button_width = 400
        self.button_height = 100
        self.cur = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        self.click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    def text_to_button(self): # defining the method for drawing a text on buttons
        bf_passive = pygame.font.SysFont('Times New Roman', 24)
        bf_passive_rend = bf_passive.render(self.button_text, 1, self.button_color_active)
        bf_passive_rect = bf_passive_rend.get_rect()

        bf_active = pygame.font.SysFont('Times New Roman', 28)
        bf_active_rend = bf_active.render(self.button_text, 1, self.button_color_passive)
        bf_active_rect = bf_active_rend.get_rect()

        if self.button_x + self.button_width > self.cur[0] > self.button_x \
                and self.button_y + self.button_height > self.cur[1] > self.button_y:
            bf_active_rect.center = (int(self.button_x + (self.button_width / 2)), int(self.button_y + (self.button_height / 2)))
            screen.blit(bf_active_rend, bf_active_rect)
        else:
            bf_passive_rect.center = (int(self.button_x + (self.button_width / 2)), int(self.button_y + (self.button_height / 2)))
            screen.blit(bf_passive_rend, bf_passive_rect)


    def draw_button(self): # defining the method for drawing button rectangle
        if self.button_x + self.button_width > self.cur[0] > self.button_x \
                and self.button_y + self.button_height > self.cur[1] > self.button_y:
           pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.button_color_passive, (self.button_x + 5, self.button_y + 5, self.button_width, self.button_height))
           pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.button_color_active, (self.button_x, self.button_y, self.button_width, self.button_height))
           if self.click[0] == 1:
               pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.button_color_passive, (self.button_x, self.button_y, self.button_width, self.button_height))
        else:
           pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.button_color_passive, (self.button_x, self.button_y, self.button_width, self.button_height))


text1 = "Text 1"

text2 = "Text 2"

while True:

    dt = clock.tick(FPS)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()

    screen.fill(bgcolor)

    text = text1

    if text == text1:
        button1 = DrawButton('Next', WIDTH - 435, HEIGHT - 150)
        button1.draw_button()
        button1.text_to_button()

    if text == text1 and button1.click[0] == 1:
        text = text2
        button2 = DrawButton('Next again', WIDTH - 435, HEIGHT - 150)
        button2.draw_button()
        button2.text_to_button()

    draw_text(screen, text, (40, 20))


    pygame.display.update()```
````

Comment: first you should create button only once - before `while`-loop - if you will create new button in every loop then you can't keep it previous stage. And you shold send new text to button as argument.

Comment: BTW: you could keep button size and position as pygame.Rect() and then you can use `rect.collide(mouse_position)` to check if mouse is inside button area

Comment: you should set `text = text1` before `while`-loop and later change it only in `if/else`

Comment: BTW: there is no need to use prefix/suffix `button` in variables in class. It is easier to use the same names for different objects - `button.draw()`, `player.draw()`, `enemy.draw()` - because you can keep them on list and use `for item in list: item.draw()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `text = text1` before loop, not inside. And then it keep new text.

But bigger problem is

```
button1.click[0] == 1
```

which is `True` all time when you keep pressed button so it makes problem to change text from first to second and later from second to first because when you keep pressed button then it changes text again and again and again - and finally you can get the same text when you release mouse button (or you can see how text is changing all the time).

You should use event `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` which is created only once - when you start pressing - but it is not created when you keep pressed.

```
text1 = "Text 1"
text2 = "Text 2"

text = text1

while True:

    dt = clock.tick(FPS)

    # --- events (without draws) ---
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if text == text1:
                text = text2
            else:
                text = text1
                
    # --- changes (without draws) ---

    if text == text1:
        button = DrawButton('Next', WIDTH-435, HEIGHT-150)
    else:
        button = DrawButton('Next again', WIDTH-435, HEIGHT-150)

    # --- draws (without changes) ---

    screen.fill(bgcolor)

    button.draw_button()
    button.text_to_button()
        
    draw_text(screen, text, (40, 20))

    pygame.display.update()
```

---

Full working code:

```
import pygame

# --- constants ---

# setting the window size and FPS
SIZE = WIDTH, HEIGHT = (640, 640)
FPS = 30

# --- classes ---

# defining a class for buttons
class DrawButton():
    
    def __init__(self, button_text, button_x, button_y):
        self.button_text = button_text
        self.button_x = button_x
        self.button_y = button_y
        self.button_color_passive = (89, 89, 89)
        self.button_color_active = (212, 200, 235)
        self.button_width = 400
        self.button_height = 100
        self.cur = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        self.click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    def text_to_button(self): # defining the method for drawing a text on buttons
        bf_passive = pygame.font.SysFont('Times New Roman', 24)
        bf_passive_rend = bf_passive.render(self.button_text, 1, self.button_color_active)
        bf_passive_rect = bf_passive_rend.get_rect()

        bf_active = pygame.font.SysFont('Times New Roman', 28)
        bf_active_rend = bf_active.render(self.button_text, 1, self.button_color_passive)
        bf_active_rect = bf_active_rend.get_rect()

        if self.button_x + self.button_width > self.cur[0] > self.button_x \
                and self.button_y + self.button_height > self.cur[1] > self.button_y:
            bf_active_rect.center = (int(self.button_x + (self.button_width / 2)), int(self.button_y + (self.button_height / 2)))
            screen.blit(bf_active_rend, bf_active_rect)
        else:
            bf_passive_rect.center = (int(self.button_x + (self.button_width / 2)), int(self.button_y + (self.button_height / 2)))
            screen.blit(bf_passive_rend, bf_passive_rect)


    def draw_button(self): # defining the method for drawing button rectangle
        if self.button_x + self.button_width > self.cur[0] > self.button_x \
                and self.button_y + self.button_height > self.cur[1] > self.button_y:
           pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.button_color_passive, (self.button_x + 5, self.button_y + 5, self.button_width, self.button_height))
           pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.button_color_active, (self.button_x, self.button_y, self.button_width, self.button_height))
           if self.click[0] == 1:
               pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.button_color_passive, (self.button_x, self.button_y, self.button_width, self.button_height))
        else:
           pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.button_color_passive, (self.button_x, self.button_y, self.button_width, self.button_height))

# --- functions ---

# defining the function to draw text on the screen
def draw_text(surface, text, pos):
    text_color = (255, 255, 255)
    text_font = pygame.font.SysFont('Times New Roman', 24)
    x, y = pos

    word_surface = text_font.render(text, 1, text_color)
    surface.blit(word_surface, (x, y))

# --- main ---

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

bgcolor = (54, 54, 54)

text1 = "Text 1"
text2 = "Text 2"

text = text1

while True:

    dt = clock.tick(FPS)

    # --- events (without draws) ---
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if text == text1:
                text = text2
            else:
                text = text1
                
    # --- changes (without draws) ---

    if text == text1:
        button = DrawButton('Next', WIDTH-435, HEIGHT-150)
    else:
        button = DrawButton('Next again', WIDTH-435, HEIGHT-150)

    # --- draws (without changes) ---

    screen.fill(bgcolor)

    button.draw_button()
    button.text_to_button()
        
    draw_text(screen, text, (40, 20))

    pygame.display.update()
```

---

**BTW:**

You could do many other changes - ie. use `pygame.Rect` to keep button size and position and later check `rect.collidepoint(mouse.pos)` to detect if mouse is over button. And use it to display it `blit(screen, image, rect)` or to center text on rect - `text_rect = text_image.get_rect(center=button_rect.center)`, etc.

All my changes

```
import pygame

# --- constants ---

# setting the window size and FPS
SIZE = WIDTH, HEIGHT = (640, 640)
FPS = 30

# --- classes ---

# defining a class for buttons

class DrawButton():
    
    def __init__(self, text, x, y, function=None):
        '''Init all needed variables only once'''

        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 400, 100)
        self.text = text
        self.function = function
        
        self.shadow_rect = self.rect.copy()
        self.shadow_rect.x += 5
        self.shadow_rect.y += 5

        self.color_passive = (89, 89, 89)
        self.color_active = (212, 200, 235)
        self.color_click = (0, 200, 0)

        self.hovered = False
        self.clicked = False

        self.font_passive = pygame.font.SysFont('Times New Roman', 24)
        self.font_active = pygame.font.SysFont('Times New Roman', 28)
        
        self.render_text()
        
    def render_text(self):
        '''Render text but don't display it'''
        
        self.passive_text = self.font_passive.render(self.text, 1, self.color_active)
        self.passive_rect = self.passive_text.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)

        self.active_text = self.font_active.render(self.text, 1, self.color_passive)
        self.active_rect = self.active_text.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)

    def handle_event(self, event):
        '''Check all events and change variables - without drawing and rendering'''
        
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            self.hovered = self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos)
            
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if self.hovered:
                self.clicked = True
                #if self.function:
                #    self.function()
                    
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if self.hovered:
                self.clicked = False
                # run function when button is released
                if self.function:
                    self.function()
        
    def draw(self, screen):
        '''Draw rectangle and text but don't render text'''
        
        if self.hovered:
            # shadow
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color_passive, self.shadow_rect)
            # rect
            if self.clicked:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color_click, self.rect)
            else:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color_active, self.rect)
            # text
            screen.blit(self.active_text, self.active_rect)
        else:
            # rect
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color_passive, self.rect)
            # text
            screen.blit(self.passive_text, self.passive_rect)

# --- functions ---

# defining the function to draw text on the screen
def draw_text(surface, text, pos):
    color = (255, 255, 255)
    
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Times New Roman', 24)
    image = font.render(text, 1, color)
    
    surface.blit(image, pos)

def on_click_1():
    global text
    
    if text == text1:
        text = text2
        button1.text = 'Next again'
        button1.render_text()
    else:
        text = text1
        button1.text = 'Next'
        button1.render_text()

def on_click_2():
    global text
    
    if text == "Hello":
        text = "World"
    else:
        text = "Hello"

# --- main ---

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

bgcolor = (54, 54, 54)

text1 = "Text 1"
text2 = "Text 2"

text = text1

# create button only once and assign function which it has to execute when it is pressed
button1 = DrawButton('Next', WIDTH-435, HEIGHT-150, on_click_1)
button2 = DrawButton('Press', WIDTH-435, HEIGHT-350, on_click_2)

while True:

    dt = clock.tick(FPS)

    # --- events ---
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        button1.handle_event(event)
        button2.handle_event(event)
        
    # --- changes (without draws) ---

    # empty
    
    # --- draws (without changes) ---
    
    screen.fill(bgcolor)
    
    button1.draw(screen)
    button2.draw(screen)
    
    draw_text(screen, text, (40, 20))

    pygame.display.update()
```